# Parsing JSON to Dataframe python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file of the format

```
{
    "keyone": {
      "col1": "or",
      "col2": "abc",
      "col3": "bcd",
      "col4": "false"
    },
    "keytwo": {
      "col1": "aaa",
      "col2": "bbb",
      "col3": "ccc",
      "col4": "true"
    },
    "keythree": {
      "col1": "zor",
      "col2": "hhh",
      "col3": "lll",
      "col4": "false"
    }
  }
```

And I wanna convert in to Pandas dataframe suck that for each key we have a row with the required values

```
key       col1    col3 
keyone    or      bcd
keytwo    and     ccc
keythree  zor     lll
```

I have looked at JSON parsers but most of them are kinda complicated.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,'index')
`

Comment: Is it JSON or is it a python dictionary?

Comment: It's in JSON @coldspeed

Comment: How does `pd.read_json(json_data, orient='index')` work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read json data like below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("""{
    "keyone": {
      "col1": "or",
      "col2": "abc",
      "col3": "bcd",
      "col4": "false"
    },
    "keytwo": {
      "col1": "aaa",
      "col2": "bbb",
      "col3": "ccc",
      "col4": "true"
    },
    "keythree": {
      "col1": "zor",
      "col2": "hhh",
      "col3": "lll",
      "col4": "false"
    }
  }""")
df.T
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pandas` to read the file in directly like

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.read_json("""{
    "keyone": {
      "col1": "or",
      "col2": "abc",
      "col3": "bcd",
      "col4": "false"
    },
    "keytwo": {
      "col1": "aaa",
      "col2": "bbb",
      "col3": "ccc",
      "col4": "true"
    },
    "keythree": {
      "col1": "zor",
      "col2": "hhh",
      "col3": "lll",
      "col4": "false"
    }
  }""")

df.T
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the other one posted?